on screen keyboard dont work properly
some keys in my computer a weak so I use on screen keyboard but since update has been imposible use ctrl combined whit virtual keys.
how can I solve this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This answer does not apply to Ubuntu 24.04, the onscreen keyboard has all of the keys necessary.
If you are running 22.04 or 23.10 you can use Improved OSK simply search for it in your extension manager, https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4413/improved-osk/
